# 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin must be a valid version but is '${weblogic.version}'

Tags: oracle, maven, weblogic, pom.xml

I am trying to run `mvn install` but I am getting following error:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin must be a valid version but is '${weblogic.version}'.
```

I checked my pom.xml and the plugin is mentioned as below:

```
...
<groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
<artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${weblogic.version}</version>
...
```

I know that version of my weblogic is 10.3.6.0. However, if I don't want to specifically there version, is there an way to resolve the error?

Comment: The property is not defined....

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.